# Updating HTML view when Angular array changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code below I change an object value in the array's first item, but I am having trouble figuring out how to "refresh" the HTML view so that what you see in the browser reflects the forced change.

```js
        var dataArray = [{
            name: 'fax.doc',
            size: 100,
        }, {
            name: 'fax.pdf',
            size: 110,
        }, {
            name: 'fax.xls',
            size: 120,
        }];    
    
        (function() {
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

                app.controller('AppController', function() {
                    this.files = dataArray;
            });


        })();
            
        function changeSomething() {
        
            dataArray[0].name = "facsimile.doc";
           // alert(dataArray[0].name);
        }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body ng-controller="AppController as box" onload="changeSomething()">

    <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="file in box.files">
            <td>{{file.name}}</td>
            <td>{{file.size}} bytes</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it will be automatically change in *angularjs*

Comment: Bcz you are changing your array out of scope of angular js and angular is not aware of your changes so it is not updating view..

Comment: @Peterson this is not stupidity i think, may be he is trying to play with angularjs to understand it better?

Answer (score 2):

Something needs to be called from within the Angular context.  C

hange the app.controller part to be:

```
 app.controller('AppController', function() {
     this.files = dataArray;

     this.changeSomething = function() {
         dataArray[0].name = "facsimile.doc";
         alert(dataArray[0].name);
     };
 });
```

and the html to be:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as box" ng-init="box.changeSomething()">
```

Comment: Your solution can't work. **box.changeSomething()** can't be recognized by **onload** event. Instead use **ng-init** there.

Comment: It's not a solution but a hint at what is wrong.  Create a plunker  and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **onload()**(native javascript) you can use **ng-init()**(native angularjs) , to change the values :

**CONTROLLER(your function into the controller):**

```
app.controller('AppController', function() {
              var vm = this;
                vm.files = dataArray;

                vm.changeSomething= function() {
                  vm.files[0].name = "facsimile.doc";
                   alert(dataArray[0].name);
                 };
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as box" ng-init="changeSomething()">
    //your code here 
</body>
```